# PHP connecting to mySQL - Access denied

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following bit of code:

```
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="admin"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="my_db_m"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB :".mysql_error());

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
```

When I attempt to login, I get: 
**cannot select DB :Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'my_db_m'**

I am using xampp. I used phpMyAdmin to create a database called 'my_db_m'. I created a table named 'members'.

Am I missing something? I am connecting to the mysql server yet unable to access the database...

Comment: You need to grant permissions to the user that allows that user access to a specific database.

Comment: obligatory notice: `mysql` is deprecated. please use `mysqli`.

Comment: Did you `GRANT` access to the table for your user `admin`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to grant access to your `admin` user.

```
GRANT ALL ON my_db_m.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

This is quite sweeping as it grants all rights, and you might want to restrict access for general use to something like

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE ON my_db_m.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
```

Comment: @YokanGekkou - see the [documentation](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management) for user management.

Comment: If you're using phpMyAdmin you don't need this command: you can grant access through the Privileges tab on the home page. In a shared hosting environment the Privileges tab might be disabled and another mechanism will be used. There's a phpMyAdmin reference [here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/user_management#Editing_an_existing_user). If that doesn't help, get in touch with your ISP

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
GRANT USAGE ON my_db_m TO user@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'passwd';
```

If you'd like to grant usage to any DB use:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.*
```